# Crash on active record dynamic matchers method missing whitelist_attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Rails 4.3.2, running rails g migration or console I get this:

I removed all references to whitelist & mass_assignment.

Application.rb
    # Load the rails application
    require File.expand_path('../application', **FILE**)

```
# Initialize the rails application
MyServer::Application.initialize!

/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing': undefined method `whitelist_attributes=' for ActiveRecord::Base:Class (NoMethodError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:108:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:107:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:107:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:28:in `block in on_load'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `on_load'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:106:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `public_send'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/user/server/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:142:in `require_application_and_environment!'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:67:in `console'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
```

Comment: remove references to 'whitelist_attributes'

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true
```

In your `config/application.rb`. Then add

```
gem 'protected_attributes'
```

to your Gemfile